# mdenoise/r.denoise: How to

Tags: grass-gis

I want to use mdenoise / r.denoise but I can't get it working. I have Xubuntu 12.04 and Grass 6.4.1

GRASS tells me after installing the plugin:

```
g.extension extension=r.denoise svnurl=https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass6
Fetching <r.denoise> from GRASS-Addons SVN (be patient)...
A    r.denoise/description.html
A    r.denoise/r.denoise
A    r.denoise/Makefile
 U   r.denoise
Ausgecheckt, Revision 51599.
Compiling <r.denoise>...
Makefile:5: /usr/lib/grass64/include/Make/Script.make: Datei
oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
make: *** Keine Regel, um
»/usr/lib/grass64/include/Make/Script.make« zu erstellen.
Schluss.
ERROR: Compilation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.
```

I got no solution for that so I tried to use mdenoise in the terminal but here I got trouble with the file extensions: ASC-is the only extension I can work with but I got a "memory access error". Converting to other extensions failed (using SAGA).

```
root@MAP-PC:~/mdenoise# /home/map/mdenoise/mdenoise -I esri.asc -o output.asc
Input File: esri.asc
Neighbourhood: Common Vertex
Threshold: 0.400000
n1: 20
n2: 50
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
root@MAP-PC:~/mdenoise#
```

with xyz-extension:

```
root@MAP-PC:~/mdenoise# /home/map/mdenoise/mdenoise -I esri.xyz -o output.asc
Input File: esri.xyz
Neighbourhood: Common Vertex
Threshold: 0.400000
n1: 20
n2: 50
Read Model...
Triangulation...
    13.620 seconds
Denoising Model...     0.000 seconds
Saving Model...No .prj file is found.
     0.120 seconds
root@MAP-PC:~/mdenoise#
```

I'm working now 10 hours non-stop on it! I'm going crazy!

I really hope, someone can help me, to get mdenoise running!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compile GRASS Addons, you need to install the "grass-dev[el]" package as well (looks like missing in your case). But it is highly recommended to use GRASS 6.4.2 since we fixed a series of (Ubuntu) problems of g.extension in this release. In GRASS 6.4.2 you find also a convenient install tool in the wxGUI, the graphical user interface.